# Get returned value from java method with GWT's JSNI

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I'm trying to get the returned value from a java method, but it returns something very strange: it returns the method itself written in javascript I think.

Here the code of the java method:

```
public String getNameToShow() {
        return "Chart number 1";
    }
```

and the javascript method:

```
 public native void drawJSChart(String divId, int a, String jsData) /*-{
            try {
                //First create a script where to paste the jsData
                var scriptID = this.@myPackage.MyClass::getNameToShow();
                console.log(scriptID);
                //Some code
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.message);
            }
        }-*/;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the types of your Java function too. Writing it like this works:

```
package XXXXX.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;

class _24_TestJSNIMethodCallback implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        drawJSChart();
    }

    public String getNameToShow() {
        return "Chart number 1";
    }

    public native void drawJSChart() /*-{
        try {
            //First create a script where to paste the jsData 
            var scriptID = this
                    .@XXXXX.client._24_TestJSNIMethodCallback::getNameToShow()();
            $wnd.alert(scriptID);
            //Some code 
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    }-*/;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, I was wonding why it didn't return what I expect!

Answer (score 5):

It returns js method because, you've asked for js method.

Invocation of java methods from JSNI code should look like this:

```
var scriptID = this.@myPackage.MyClass::getNameToShow(*)(); //notice second pair of braces
```

Basically to invoke java method from JSNI, you will need to place two pairs of braces. First defines method parameter types (in my example I've used `*` so it will match any parameter types), second is used to pass parameters into the method.